# Is there a neutral way of saying "deliberately"?

Tags: word-choice

I wrote a sentence which involved [故意](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%95%85%E6%84%8F) (gùyì; deliberately) and my teacher explained that 故意 is a negative word: you can't deliberately do something good using 故意.  (I won't reproduce that sentence, since it contains other errors.)

But in English, "deliberately" ("intentionally"; "on purpose") is not necessarily a bad thing.

> To help the students understand her, our teacher deliberately speaks slowly.

I might translate this to

> 为了让学生明白她说的，我们的老师故意地说得慢。

but then we have the problem of 故意 being negative.  I'm not sure if [有意](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%9C%89%E6%84%8F) has the same issue, but it seems very similar to 故意.

**Question**: Is there a neutral way of saying "deliberately"?

Comment: 老師 特意 說的很慢。 特意 is intentionally.

Comment: @TooskyHierot Try not to leave answers in the comments section, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'故意' implying someone intend to do some bad things. If you want to say someone intend to do things specially. You can use '特意'. This word do not imply any bad or good intention. It only emphasize 'specially'. But in most of case, Chinese love to use it in positive senarios, like me.

> 为了让学生听得明白，我们老师特意把语速放慢。
>
> 在下班的路上，他特意绕路去医院看望母亲。

Answer (score 2):

Try:

> 为了让学生听得明白，我们老师**有意识地**把语速放慢。

有意 or 有意识地 doesn't have a negative connotation.

Another good word that can fit for this context is **刻意**.

> 为了让学生听明白，老师**刻意**放慢了语速。

I personally prefer 有意识地 for the context. It's because 有意识地 implies that you have realized something and then you deliberately make some adjustments to accommodate it. In OP's case, the teacher realized that the speed of his/her speaking mattered, so he/she deliberately spoke slowly.

But other words 刻意，特意（suggested by others）can fit as well.